# video em html5 com altura fixa e largura maleável

Tags: html5, youtube, vídeo

Eu tenho que fazer um vídeo onde tem um altura fixa e uma largura de 100%, o problema é que quando utilizo height:100% não funciona e se eu usar height:auto; com width:100%; também não funciona por que o vídeo fica da altura original dele, o que eu gostaria era que o vídeo fosse 100% de altura e de lagura mas respeitando o container que ele está. 
Se alguém tiver alguma ideia agradeço por que todas que eu encontrei não funcionam. Se alguém souber com iframe pode ser também.

**CSS**

```
.container{ width:100%; height:732px; float:left; position:relative; }
.container video{ width:100%; height:100%; float:left; }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <video controls src="videos/video1.mp4"></video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sua pergunta não está muito clara. Caso você queira que um elemento filho herde a largura e altura de seu elemento pai (`.container`), veja meu exemplo:
http://codepen.io/ahlechandre/pen/PqvJJQ